# XPages Date picker in a modal

Tags: datepicker, modal-dialog, xpages, bootstrap-modal

If I use the standard date picker control, on a normal xpage, everything works perfectly, however, if I have it within a modal, when I call the modal, and the field displays fine, but if I then click on the picker icon, the calendar only flashes up and just disappears so that I can't actually select a date.

Has anyone had any issues / resolutions to this? Modal code below:

```
<!-- Modal ONE -->
    <div class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static"
        tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalDueDate">

        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header modal-header-default">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Change Due Date</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <xp:inputText id="dtChangeDueDate">
                        <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper1" />
                        <xp:this.converter>
                            <xp:convertDateTime type="date" />
                        </xp:this.converter>
                    </xp:inputText>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <xp:button type="button" styleClass="btn btn-danger" id="button4">

                        <xp:this.attrs>
                            <xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="modal" />
                            <xp:attr name="data-target" value="#modalDueDate" />
                        </xp:this.attrs>
                        Cancel
                    </xp:button>

                    <xp:button type="button" styleClass="btn btn-success" id="button5">
                        <xp:this.attrs>
                            <xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="modal" />
                            <xp:attr name="data-target" value="#modalDueDate" />
                        </xp:this.attrs>
                        Update

                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                            refreshMode="complete">
                            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:try{

var noteID:string = compositeData.noteID;
print ("Parent NoteID: " + noteID)

var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByID(noteID);
var dueDate = getComponent("dtChangeDueDate").getValue();
//var oldDueDate = doc.getItemValueString("DueDate");

var docWrap = wrapDocument(doc);

var dt = new Date();
var arrHistory:array = AddObjectivesHistoryItem(docWrap, dt, "Due Date Changed To "+dueDate, userBean.displayName);

docWrap.replaceItemValue("DueDate",dueDate);
docWrap.save();

var o = {}
o.title = "Due Date Updated";
o.body = "The due date has been succesfully updated to " + dueDate;
o.alertIcon = "fa-thumbs-up fa-lg";
o.autoClose = true;
o.alertType = "success";
//o.growl = true;
requestScope.put("alertServer",o)


}catch(e){
    openLogBean.addError(e,this.getParent());
}}]]></xp:this.action>
                        </xp:eventHandler>
                    </xp:button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- Modal ONE End-->
```

Comment: Never tried that combination. But as the xps calendar pop-up is based on dojo I'm not surprised it clashes with bootstrap. Have you tried using some type of a bootstrap-datepicker instead and connect it to a standard input field?

Answer (score 1):

Check the relative z-index css settings for the modal and the date-time helper. I don't know if the z-index of the modal is putting it in front of the picker. I'd also look at the Network tab in whatever browser developer tools you're using to see if there's anything unusual there.